# (QT) include libraries from Linux for Windows application using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt, window, cross-compiling

Since QT is a cross-platform development tool, compiling the c++ code for different OS is no doubt feasible. But, what if, the c++ code include other c++ code that include other OS libraries that are different from the target OS.

My situation is that I have a source code using linux libraries, and I would like to include that source code in my QT project for Windows application.

For now, I've tried look up all those included Linux header and source files and copy them from linux into my QT project folder. The barrier is that it's too time-consuming. I am trying to google topics on my situation, but it seems that no results match my concern. Can anyone give me a guide on how to achieve my goal? or should I give up using the Linux source code in the first place?

Appreciate for any helps in advance.

Comment: Try to find out source code of those Linux libraries from original sources (websites/Github) there you will get all files together and then compile it on Windows  that is the only way this will only work if those libraries are compatible with windows. Otherwise try to find out similar libs for windows instead of copy pasting from linux

Comment: Thanks SourabhKus! You mean even if I copy the linux source code from Github, I still got chance that it won't work, since the code may originally be incompatible with windows. As your suggestion, the best way is to find out similar windows library. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes try to find out similar libraries for windows otherwise you will end up like reinventing the wheel.